# Loading json data to highstocks with multiple series and adding TimeStamp to xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to load json data to multiple series and add Time to xAxis in HighStock?
And any idea how to add multiple yAxis on the right and left of the HighStock chart?
I tried to convert to json structure ["name": data:[]] but i can't find how to do it. Please help.

My code is in ASP.Net MVC 4:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
  {

     var chart = new List<object>();
     chart.Add( new { Speed = 50, Tank = 201.56, odomoter = 2319.956, Time = "05/04/2015 23:53:07" } );
     chart.Add( new { Speed = 80, Tank = 201.56, odomoter = 2319.956, Time = "05/04/2015 23:52:06" } );
     chart.Add( new { Speed = 90, Tank = 201.56, odomoter = 2191.907, Time = "05/04/2015 23:51:06" } );
     var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     var output = jss.Serialize( chart );
     return Json( output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
  }
```

```js
$(function () {

            $.getJSON('GetData', function(jdata) {
                alert(jdata);
            
                       // Create the chart
                       $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

                           chart: {
                               type: 'spline',
                               zoomType: 'xy'
                           },
                           rangeSelector: {
                               buttons: [{
                                   type: 'hour',
                                   count: 1,
                                   text: '1h'
                               }, {
                                   type: 'day',
                                   count: 2,
                                   text: '2d'
                               }, {
                                   type: 'week',
                                   count: 1,
                                   text: '1w'
                               }, {
                                   type: 'month',
                                   count: 1,
                                   text: '1m'
                               }, {
                                   type: 'year',
                                   count: 1,
                                   text: '1y'
                               }, {
                                   type: 'all',
                                   text: 'All'
                               }],
                               inputEnabled: true, // it supports only days
                               selected: 0 // day
                           },
                           //xAxis: {

                           //    minRange: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                           //    type: 'datetime',
                           //    dateTimeLabelFormats: { minute: '%H:%M', day: '%A. %e/%m' },
                           //    // minRange: 15*60*1000,
                           //    //maxZoom: 48 * 3600 * 1000,
                           //    labels: {
                           //        rotation: 330,
                           //        y: 20,
                           //        staggerLines: 1
                           //    }
                           //},
                           yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                               labels: {
                                   format: '{value}°C',
                                   style: {
                                       color: '#89A54E'
                                   }
                               },
                               title: {
                                   text: 'Temperature',
                                   style: {
                                       color: '#89A54E'
                                   }
                               }
                           }, { // Secondary yAxis
                               title: {
                                   text: 'Consumo',
                                   style: {
                                       color: '#4572A7'
                                   }
                               },
                               labels: {
                                   format: '{value} Kw',
                                   style: {
                                       color: '#4572A7'
                                   }
                               },
                               opposite: true
                           }],
                           title: {
                               text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
                           },
                           series: data

                           //series: [{
                           //    name: 'AAPL',
                           //    data: data,
                           //    tooltip: {
                           //        valueDecimals: 2
                           //    }
                           //}]
                       });
                   });

               });
```

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`. Then copy&paste example data into the question. There may be a lot of issues, like improper format, or string data instead of numbers etc. Also, copy&paste errors from **Javascript** console.

Comment: I'm converting data from SQL server https://jsfiddle.net/tmdyqm5q/

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't address any of my requests: 1) Show the data you get in the HTML. 2) Do you have any Javascript errors?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tmdyqm5q/3/ . Yes, I got JavaScript error.
765 console messages are not shown.
1176highstock.js:13 Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15. Text Visualizer shows {"key":1429523896000.0,"value":0},{"key":1429523835000.0,"value":0}

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is to convert sql server datetime to json unix timestamp

Comment: So, according to your error, you need to sort your data ascending. So: `{"key":1429523896000.0,"value":0},{"key":1429523835000.0,"value":0}` -> `{"key":1429523835000.0,"value":0},{"key":1429523896000.0,"value":0}`